# Import error when loading jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, jupyter

I'm trying to open an ipython notebook and I get the following error:

```
jupyter notebook

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jguedes/anaconda/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 4, in <module>
import notebook.notebookapp
File "/Users/jguedes/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook   /notebookapp.py", line 61, in <module>
from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
File "/Users/jguedes/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 16, in <module>
from nbformat import sign, validate, ValidationError
File "/Users/jguedes/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
from .validator import validate, ValidationError
File "/Users/jguedes/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/validator.py", line 21, in <module>
raise ImportError(str(e) + verbose_msg)
ImportError: No module named _version

Jupyter notebook format depends on the jsonschema package:

    https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema

Please install it first.
```

In order to install jupyter I used

```
conda install jupyter
```

Any help with this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try it install with pip3?

Comment: No, I didn't try. I'm working with python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

Try updating `conda` first:

```
conda update conda
conda update --all
```

And then install `jupyter` as before:

```
conda install jupyter
```

Comment: That probably works, because pip install -U jsonschema did the trick.